# SSRS 2008 R2 - cannot logon to localhost/reports

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When attempting to deploy a SSRS 2008 R2 Report to my localhost/ReportServer, or trying to login to localhost/reportserver (via web browser), I am not able to get any further than a security error message.

When trying to access the report server via a web browser, I'm prompted to enter my login credentials.  Even though I am the admin on the box, I still receive the following message:

> User 'PCName\Me' does not have
>   required permissions. Verify that
>   sufficient permissions have been
>   granted and Windows User Account
>   Control (UAC) restrictions have been
>   addressed.

I have also tried launching my browser in Administrator Mode - same issue.

When attempting to deploy a report from VS, I get a similar message:

> The permissions granted to user
>   'PCName\Me' are insufficient for
>   performing this operation.

Some assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to run your browser as Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark, thanks for the suggestion. I found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx) where I had to change the report server's authentication type to local.

```
<Authentication>
      <AuthenticationTypes>
             <RSWindowsBasic>
                   <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
                   <Realm></Realm>
                   <DefaultDomain></DefaultDomain>
             </RSWindowsBasic>
      </AuthenticationTypes>
      <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

This satisfies my testing needs, but not secure prod environment needs.

Answer (score 1):

"User 'PCName\Me'" sounds like a local logon - have you tried entering your domain logon (**including** the domain name before the slash - ie. *Domain Name* \ *User Name*) and password?